# UserWarning: Overwriting previously set objective. warnings.warn("Overwriting previously set objective.")

Tags: python, pandas

I am a pandas - beginner and I need your help. I really don't know why this particular msg is coming up )(Overwriting previously set objective [...].
As far as I can tell, I am not overwriting anything.

I created a pretty simple example. 
Can anybody help me out here?

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pulp import *


a = {'a' :7, 'b': 4, 'c': 4, 'd': 6, 'e': 2, 'f':1, 'g': 3, 'h': 4, 'i': 6, 'j': 1}

b = {'a' :0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f':0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0}

c = {'a' :10, 'b': 10, 'c': 10, 'd': 10, 'e': 10, 'f':10, 'g': 10, 'h': 10, 'i': 10, 'j': 10}


prob = LpProblem("Problem",LpMinimize)

p_el = pulp.LpVariable.dict( 
        "p_el_%s", range(0,2), lowBound=0, upBound=10, cat="Continuous") 

for t in range(0,2): 

    prob += ((p_el[t] + a[list(a.keys())[t]] + b[list(b.keys())[t]])) , "Total Sum"


    prob += p_el[t] + a[list(a.keys())[t]] + b[list(b.keys())[t]] == c[list(c.keys())[t]]        



    prob.writeLP("Problem.lp")
    prob.solve()


    for v in prob.variables():
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Comment: Please provide a code with proper indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong operation over prob incrementation. here is the sequence of execution,
1. loop start with value t=0. work fine.
2. The problem starts with incrementing "prob" object. if you see my screenshot you are trying to assign the incremental value "1*p_el_0+4" to prob again.
3. If you add an expression (not a constraint), it will become the **objective**.

what I found is code written inside of pulp has a magic method to hack incrementation, which generally checks for object called self.objective for None. 
since in our case it's not None its already holding ""1*p_el_0+7" causing set data structure to fail.

Please check your prob statement assignment.

[image]